# Network usage : How to monitor by time

Tags: applications, networking

I'm looking for a way that tracks network usage by type. I'd like something that at the end of the day says "8h 20min on 3G, 3h under WiFi network".

I've searched a lot but didn't find anything (there are tons of apps that tracks megabytes exchanged, but this is not my interest).

Is there a technical problem behind (i.e. lack of system APIs)?

Comment: App recommendations are off topic and is reason for closure. Since you have also awarded a bounty for it , I have taken the liberty of editing your question to avoid specific app recommendations. If that is not agreeable, please *roll back* to the original version

Comment: @Surfer on the fall, you could try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ If you are looking for a specific app recommendation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a technical difficulty in gathering such information. Lack of such apps is likely because of *lack of demand*. For an average user, it is not the *time* that is important but the *data* used while on a plan or roaming and hence an abundance of such apps

I am not aware if the information you seek can be pulled from Android OS requiring programming skill . There is an *open source* app [Network Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ca.rmen.android.networkmonitor), which can help you. It doesn't directly give you what you want, but information can easily be extracted.  App has been updated last month. Extract from app description:

> Network Monitor is a diagnostic tool which periodically tests your network connection and logs the results to a database on the phone....It also logs other information about your device and connection status, such as:
>   The network type (WiFi, mobile/EDGE, mobile/HSPA, etc)

It offers a rich selection of features to log and display. This solution shows minimum settings required to achieve your goal :

- Network Settings →  Enable Service ( Enable / disable as required per duration of monitoring)
- Network Settings →  Log frequency can be varied from 1/2 sec to 1 hour , depending on the accuracy you need
- Advanced Options → Fields to monitor - offers 50 + fields. Basic fields needed would be :

  - Timestamp
  - Network Type
  - Is connected

You can view the log file with these settings as shown in the screenshot below

[image]
[image]

Log file can be exported ( mail it yourself) in several formats (`Excel, CSV, HTML, KML, Gnuplot` the raw database) , for further analysis. Excel would be the obvious choice.

- You can filter the *Network Type* and *Is connected =1* ( to avoid disconnected times ), say for WiFi
- Use the `count` function of Excel and multiply it with *log frequency* ( i.e, time) to arrive at total time and convert it to `hh:mm` format  - my Excel is rusty, there should be better ways :)
- Repeat for mobile data